# Calling a javascript function inside a table cell

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

I have been trying to call a function inside a table cell to dynamically generate some data. But have been getting below error.
I am not sure if I am calling defined and javascripts functions correctly inside the table cell.

```
    TypeError: patient.dob.getFullYear is not a function
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/Anand/OneDrive/clinic/client/src/components/ListPt.js:64
  61 | <td>{patient.email}</td>
  62 | <td>{patient.mobile}</td>
  63 | <td>{patient.gender}</td>             
> 64 | <td>{calculate_age(new Date(patient.dob.getFullYear(), patient.dob.getMonth(), patient.dob.getDate()))}</td>
     | ^  65 | <td>{patient.address}</td>
  66 | {/* <td><EditTodo todo={todo}/></td> */}
  67 | <td><button className="btn btn-danger" >Add Treatment</button></td>
```

Full code is as below:

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";


const Listpt = () => {
  const [patients, setPatients] = useState([]);


  const getPts = async() =>{
    try {

       const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/patients")
       const jsonData = await response.json();


       setPatients(jsonData);

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);

    }
}
useEffect(() => {
    getPts();
},[]);


console.log(patients);

//Age calculator
function calculate_age(dob) { 
    var diff_ms = Date.now() - dob.getTime();
    var age_dt = new Date(diff_ms); 

    return Math.abs(age_dt.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
}

    return <Fragment>
        {" "}
       <table class="table mt-5 text-center">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>OPD No</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Mobile</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Dob</th>
        <th>Address</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

     {patients.map(patient =>(
         <tr key ={patient.patient_id}>
             <td>{patient.patient_id}</td>
             <td>{patient.name}</td>
             <td>{patient.email}</td>
             <td>{patient.mobile}</td>
             <td>{patient.gender}</td>             
             <td>{calculate_age(new Date(patient.dob.getFullYear(), patient.dob.getMonth(), patient.dob.getDate()))}</td>
             <td>{patient.address}</td>

             <td><button className="btn btn-danger" >Add Treatment</button></td>
         </tr>
     ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
    </Fragment> 

};

export default Listpt;
```

can anyone help me understand where I am going wrong on Line 64.

```
<td>{calculate_age(new Date(patient.dob.getFullYear(), patient.dob.getMonth(), patient.dob.getDate()))}</td>
```

Comment: `patient.dob` is not a Date object's instance. If its a string, you could use directly `new Date(patient.dob)`

Comment: patient.dob is most likely a string instead of date.

Comment: Looks like `patient.dob` isn't a valid Dtate object from which you can call `getFullYear`.

Comment: It's not the problem, but your code is falling prey to the footgun in the `fetch` API: You need to check for HTTP success by checking `response.ok` before calling the `json` method. Details in [this post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) on my anemic little blog.

Comment: adding new Date did it...Thanks Anurag...cheers!

Answer (score 1):

`getFullYear` is a method found on `Date` objects.

`patient.dob` can't be a `Date` object because JSON has no such thing.

It is *probably* a string. You need to identify the format of that string and convert it to a `Date` object.